# How to safely update jobs in-flight using Apache Flink on AWS EMR?

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

I was not able to find instructions for how to update code safely.  I see Flink docs on how to use savepoints.  I'd expect an easy solution for updating Flink jobs in AWS EMR.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/deployment/aws.html

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/upgrading.html

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html

I was expecting instructions like the following (but not for Dataflow and Apache Beam):

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline

https://medium.com/google-cloud/restarting-cloud-dataflow-in-flight-9c688c49adfd

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that You need to cancel Your job with savepoint whether by using Flink [command line](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/cli.html) interface or via the [REST API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html). In both cases, You will receive the path for the savepoint(in case of REST API you will receive the request-id since cancel is an async operation, but You can use that to retrieve savepoint path).

After getting the savepoint path, You will be able to start a new job, again both via REST API or CLI, you will be able to provide the path to the savepoint when starting the job so that Flink will automatically restore the state from Savepoint, including all records that were in-flight.

Comment: I have a followup question. 
You have described a "stand alone" procedure for this. Does AWS EMR automate this in some way, for example via their API?  I would expect something similar to EMR CLI command like we have for submitting long running jobs.

Comment: Ahh, sorry mate. Are You using YARN for that ?

Comment: I will be using AWS EMR, so i guess it is powered by YARN.